# Encrypted Credentials in JSON [Serialize JSON in C#]

Tags: c#, json

I want mine
Now store encrypted access data in JSON files. My idea is to query this data in C # and decrypt it, but I do not know how to get started. Unfortunately, I have no experience in JSON, would be glad about an answer, thx.

**EDIT**

***It was about Serialize JSON in C#.
I used it for Credentials***

Comment: So, where are you stuck? JSON or encryption/decryption?

Comment: At JSON, want to store the result of the encryption in there

Comment: In that case, for C# you probably want to use [NewtonSoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). You can find docs and examples all over the net.

Comment: You can use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Comment: assuming the encrypted data is in string format, then you can store it in a JSON object the same as any other kind of data. So you can just find out how to create JSON objects, and that should answer your query.

Comment: @Fildor , i have it, it was pretty simple to create the objects on C# thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Many thanks to @Fildor**

Thats the code i looked for:

```
    Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```